# Xamarin/Visual Studio Mac Blank Forms Project Errors

Tags: android, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, android-appcompat

I am fully aware similar questions have been asked (and answered) However, nothing has worked for my particular case. The issue occurs in Visual Studio for Mac when trying to create a new Xamarin Forms Blank project. As soon as the project is created there are already errors:

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.3.0'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v2.3', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

From the solutions I have read, people have said I must have the same Target Android/API and Target Framework version. Ive tried with several versions of android, however VS wont allow me to edit the Target Framework: 
[image]

Ive so I set the Target Android version to be Android 7.1 (API 25)
[image]

Also it seems that the packages folder under the Xamarin Droid project is empty, so i try to install the NuGet packages needed

> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat

And the same errors occur. This is frustrating because I cant even start to develop or test my code immediately out of the box Xamarin/VS has issues.

If anybody knows how to help, please be very specific, everything else online has been very vague, "need to update Xamarin.Forms" or something without much detail or procedural explanation. I know many many others are having similar issues with VS/Xamarin on MacOS. Here is my package structure: 
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this too.

The root cause was that I had no Android SDK accessible to my user, so there was no target platform to choose and no nuget packages were installed.

I ended up doing the following:

- Install Android Studio with all the defaults and install a few Android SDK levels with the Android Studio SDK manager.
- Get the SDK path from Android Studio and paste it into the Preferences/SDK Locations in Visual Studio.
- Restart Visual Studio and create a new project - it will install some nuget packages this time.
- Open the options for the Android project and choose suitable minimum and target Android versions under Android Application.

The project should build now.

Comment: After installing multiple SDKs and Failing with all of them to get this installed I restarted visual studio and it suddenly worked, it seems as though VS on Mac is very buggy and inconsistent because I fixed the same error last week and when I tried to replicate the steps it didn't work this time, then I restart VS and voilà

Answer (score 1):

When you install Visual Studio for Mac, there is a step to check to install Android SDK. You can check whether Android SDK is install or not in Visual Studio->Preferences->SDK Locations->Android
[image]

The step to install Android SDK is here. You need to select **Android** then check the **Android SDK** on the right side. Yes, its weird that it is not selected by default =.=:
[image]

Details guide of the installation can be refer https://lowleetak.wordpress.com/2017/07/01/xamarin-installation-in-mac/

Comment: Thank you but I did all that when I installed VS

Comment: so your Android SDK is installed properly? Do you have any error in the Configure SDK Locations dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known bug with VS for Mac:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96085/could-not-add-packages